# Can a person refuse a presidential pardon?

Tags: united-states, president, pardon

Michael Cohen, a former personal attorney of President Trump, in recent testimony before Congress, stated he would not accept a presidential pardon. Is this an option he has? If a pardon nullifies a committed crime, it seems like he should not be allowed to choose if he goes to prison or not because as far as the federal government is concerned, the crime is forgiven. An average person could not go to prison if a jury found them innocent. Why is this different?

Comment: It's worth correcting the opening statement of the OP's question. Michael Cohen did not say that he would not accept a presidential pardon. The transcript (https://www.nytimes.com/2019/02/27/us/politics/cohen-documents-testimony.html) of the opening statement of his testimony shows that he said, "I have never asked for, nor would I accept, a pardon from President Trump." That's quite a different matter from the more general assertion that he would not accept a presidential pardon.

Comment: A pardon does not nullify the crime. A pardon forgives the guilty plea for a crime (you cannot pardon a non-guilty party). Thus a person may reject a pardon if they intend to prove their innocence.

Comment: @user02814 maybe my English is not good but doesn't *"I have never asked for, nor would I accept, a pardon from President Trump."* basically mean *"I have never asked for a pardon from President Trump."* **and** *"I would not accept a pardon from President Trump."* ?

Comment: @zakinster yes indeed - but I think user02814's point is that Cohen's assertion leaves open the question of accepting a presidential pardon from a president other than Trump.

Comment: @JulienLopez why would they be prohibited? Because it's a nonsense situation, it doesn't need a rule

Comment: Another reason to decline a pardon could be **if you really believed you deserved the punishment**. Perhaps you murdered someone you were very close with, and you immediately turned yourself in due to guilt.

Comment: @slebetman A guilty plea is unnecessary.  Nothing needs to have even gone to a prosecutor's desk yet.  You don't even have to be particularly specific about what's being pardoned. Ford pardoned Nixon for *all* crimes committed within the time frame of Watergate, with no restrictions, but Nixon never conceded to any criminal wrongdoing. Trump pardoned Arapaio, who had staunchly refused to admit any wrongdoing (though it was specific about exactly which legal violations were covered).

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I'm not exactly sure about the Nixon case but Arapaio's status is legally guilty of all the wrongdoings that he was pardoned for - he verbally refuse to admit it but legally he can no longer do certain things like run for office because of his implicit guilty plea by accepting the pardon.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It is possible to reject a pardon.  Referring to [United States v. Wilson](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/32/150/):

> There is nothing peculiar in a pardon which ought to distinguish it in
>   this respect from other facts; no legal principle known to the court
>   will sustain such a distinction. A pardon is a deed to the validity of
>   which delivery is essential, and delivery is not complete without
>   acceptance. It may then be rejected by the person to whom it is
>   tendered, and if it be rejected, we have discovered no power in a
>   court to force it on him.

There are also other practical effects to accepting pardons, such as waiving of fifth amendment rights relating to the pardoned crimes, since it would be impossible to self incriminate anymore.  So there are reasons to refuse beyond "choosing to go to prison".

Comment: I get a kick out of this part of that decision: "The power of pardon in criminal cases had been exercised from time immemorial by the executive of that nation whose language is our language, and to whose judicial institutions ours bear a close resemblance." Was this really a necessary phrasing on their part?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy - Early 1800s, maybe they still viewed England as be a Valdemort type of entity.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on the implications of waiving fifth amendment rights on accepting a pardon?

Comment: @Mindwin If you get asked a question under oath which would force you to admit to a crime if answered truthfully, i.e you would incriminate yourself as to having commited a crime, then you can choose not to answer by "pleading the fifth" e.g. invoking the fifth amendment's protection against self incrimination. Most western nations have this right. If you get pardoned for a crime, it's essentially not a crime anymore, so you can't rely on fifth amendment protections to allow you to opt out of being asked about the details.

Comment: @magish I have posted it as its own question https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/39112/7734

Comment: @PoloHoleSet in a recent ruiling (Timbs v. Indiana), SCOTUS talks about Magna Carta to establish the length of precedent for the basis of their ruling. They are acknowledging that US law didn't spring from nothing in 1776

Comment: @Caleth - I'm making a joke about the wording.

Comment: Re: "It's essentially not a crime anymore". In today's world, simply answering questions, even when done truthfully, is likely to incriminate you if the prosecutor decides they want to nail you to the cross. There's all kinds of games that can be played that allows a prosecutor to charge someone for perjury even knowing full-well that there was no intent to lie by the person being charged. I'm surprised anybody would ever say anything to anyone anymore.

Comment: My understanding is that prosecutors can give people immunity, making the fifth amendment not apply, and the witness can't refuse to accept immunity.

Comment: It's worth noting that while you can turn down a pardon, you [cannot](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/274/480/) turn down a commutation (a similar, but slightly different act).

Comment: @bta How would you even turn down a commutation? Refuse to leave jail?

Comment: @AzorAhai exactly. When you refuse to leave jail, you're trespassing. Get arrested, boom back in jail.

Comment: I'm no lawyer but  United States v. Wilson sounds wrong to me.  I see pardon as not something given to a person to use if they see fit to stop a prosecution or get out of jail, but rather a fact that the prosecutors or jailer must recognize.  If there's suddenly no crime by reason of pardon then the prosecution stops, just as any other prosecution stops once it discovers some evidence that there is no crime.  The defendant cannot force govt to prosecute them despite there being no crime.  Once sentenced, exonerating evidence isn't necessarily taken up by the justice system though.

Answer (score 67):

The question is theoretical. But there's no need to theorize. There's at least one case of a convict successfully rejecting a presidential pardon. The Supreme Court ruled on [this case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Wilson) in 1833, saying a pardon is *"not completed without acceptance"*.

The case is touched upon in [a previous answer to this post](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/39101/12464).

Here are excerpts from an article describing the case:

> [The Man Who Refused A
>   Pardon](https://www.cbmcint.com/the-man-who-refused-a-pardon/) ~ CBMC
>   International
>
> In 1829 two men, George Wilson and James Porter, robbed a United
>   States mail carrier. Both were subsequently captured and tried in a
>   court of law.
>
> In May 1830 both men were found guilty of six charges, including
>   robbery of the mail "and putting the life of the driver in jeopardy."
>
> Both Wilson and Porter received their sentences: Execution by hanging,
>   to be carried out on July 2. Porter was executed on schedule, but Wilson was not.
>
> Influential friends pleaded for mercy to the President of the United
>   States, Andrew Jackson, on his behalf. **President Jackson issued a
>   formal pardon, dropping all charges.** Wilson would have to serve only a
>   prison term of 20 years for his other crimes.
>
> Incredibly, **George Wilson refused the pardon!**
>
> An official report stated Wilson chose to "waive and decline any
>   advantage or protection which might be supposed to arise from the
>   pardon…."
>
> *The U.S. Supreme Court determined, "The court cannot give the prisoner
>   the benefit of the pardon, unless he claims the benefit of it... It is
>   a grant to him: it is his property; and he may accept it or not as he
>   pleases."*
>
> *Chief Justice John Marshall wrote, "A pardon is an act of
>   grace, proceeding from the power entrusted with the execution of the
>   laws... (But) delivery is not completed without acceptance. It may
>   then be rejected by the person to whom it is tendered, and... we have
>   no power in a court to force it on him."*
>
> <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Reference:

- [United States v. Wilson, 1833](http://press-pubs.uchicago.edu/founders/documents/a2_2_1s29.html)

Comment: If a pardon is not completed without acceptance, what does that mean for posthumous pardons?

Comment: Like for any legal matter, the pardon can be accepted or challenged by the deceased person's estate. But I would presume that in such cases acceptance is simply implied. @CactusCake

Answer (score 3):

Certainly in the UK at least one person has refused a pardon, on the grounds that accepting the pardon implied their accepting the guilt of the action in the first place. They were attempting to prove they did not commit the act in the first place.

There is a difference between 'you did it but we forgive you' and 'you didn't do it' and the person wanted to prove they didn't do it. The same could hold true for a presidential pardon, but I suspect that Michael Cohen, having admitted his guilt, is making a different point.

Comment: Welcome to [politics.se]! However, I don't really see how this answers the question. The fact that someone in the UK refused a pardon doesn't say anything about whether or not someone in the U.S. can refuse a pardon. The rest of this answer is speculation about Michael Cohen's motives. Whether or not Cohen is trying to avoid an implication of guilt, *can* he refuse a presidential pardon?

Comment: @houninym Who was that person? Adding that detail would make this an interesting and useful answer.

Comment: @Null US law is based on English law as it existed in 1776. Many other countries' laws are also based on English law, from Canada, Australia, India, China, Thailand and many others.  SCOTUS often refers to foreign judgements as points of comparison even though they are obviously not binding, and other countries do the same to SCOTUS judgements. People refusing pardons in other countries is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Frank Abagnale has famously turned down 3 presidential pardons. Though in his case all were after the prison sentence had been served.